# Android ActionBar Action title before icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, action

im looking for creating an action bar like this:

X Cancel -------------- add +

where X and + are icons. So im using getActionBar.setIcon to set the X. home action to set the Cancel title. the ---------- stuf is just blank space, An action with title and icon to set the "add" and the "+", the problem is that by default the action shows the icon to the left side of the title. so im having:

X Cancel -------------- + add

Is there a way to flip it? 
or maeby a better way to do this....

i realy was unmotivated to use a custom layout for the action bar cuz i think i lose the power of action items...

here is the menu xml:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_create_key"
    android:icon="@drawable/plus"
    android:title="@string/action_create"
    android:showAsAction="always|withText"/>
```

Thanks a lot for ur time and help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why would you not like to use custom layout for action bar? you can also add the actions to the items in the custom layout too. 
Simply create the custom layout of your desired design and use following code to handle it

```
final ViewGroup actionBarLayout = (ViewGroup) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setCustomView(actionBarLayout);

    ImageView cancel = (ImageView) actionBarLayout.findViewById(R.id.cancel_icon);
    ImageView add = (ImageView) actionBarLayout.findViewById(R.id.add_icon);

    cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

          //add your functionaity
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something that can be done using stock ActionBar items. You could consider using the [Done/Discard custom action bar](https://plus.google.com/+RomanNurik/posts/R49wVvcDoEW), which uses a custom layout of two buttons as the action bar, replacing 'Discard`and`Done`for your`Cancel`and`Add`. If you are using the provided [DoneBarActivity source code][2], you'd want to change the right hand layout to use`drawableRight`rather than`drawableLeft` to position your icon to the right of the text.